# Get mean squared error between every element in two tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have two single dimensional tensors, `y_pred` and `y_true`
where:

```
>>> y_pred.shape
torch.Size([2730441, 1])
>>> y_true.shape
torch.Size([2730441, 1])
```

To get the Mean Squared Error between the two tensors I can use
`torch.nn.MSELoss()` However, I want to get the loss between each row/ element in the tensors `y_pred` & `y_true` i.e. I want to run some function `elementWiseMSE(y_pred, y_true)` which will return `loss_tensor` of shape `[2730441, 1]` which contains the elementwise mean error of all the predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "function" you are looking for is literally

```
loss_tensor = (y_pred - y_true) ** 2
```